# Get a facebook numeric id and profile picture w/o facebook api or facebook sdk

Tags: image, facebook, profile

I have a question. Is there a possible way to get someone's
profile numeric id and profile picture, **WITHOUT using an Acces token**, facebook SDK or API. Just with scripts?

I have this code:

```
function GetProfilePicture() 
{
var userId=prompt('userID please','id here')
var imglink="<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture? type=large'>"

document.getElementById('profilepicture').innerHTML=imglink;
}
```

This code used to paste the profile picture of the user
in the HTML element named "profile picture", but due to
changed in facebook, this doesn't work anymore. Instead of the user id (eg.: JohnDoe), you need the numeric id to Make
this code work. Is there Any script i can include in my code
so it displays the profile picture after giving the FaceBook id?

Before people start thinking wrong about me:
I am ONLY using this numeric id thing to retrieve name & 
profile picture. I am not mailing/spoofing/hijacking something! The only thing i want to get out of the url is the
numeric ID, and a way to get the profile name and the profile picture. I am only using this for LEGAL PURPOSES.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No there is no way to map username to user id

Comment: Hmmm. I believe you, but do you have an idea how sites like http://findfacebookid.com do the job? I just need this code :) . Thank you for your response, sir.

Comment: They scrape Facebook which is not allowed

Comment: Then, is there a way if you use the FaceBook sdk and the Acces token? I wont ask about that scraping as i do not know if i am allowed to ask about that type of tsuff on stackoverflow (new here :] )  So is there a 'good' way of retrieving this information? thank you

Comment: That I already answered. No there is no way

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help ;). (P.s.: how do i close this thread??? *_*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to retrieve this information without violating the terms of service of facebook. 
If i may find a way later (when the ToS changes for example). I'll post it here.